# Windows server performance monitoring tool with email

Tags: sql-server, monitoring

We have an SQL server 2005 on Windows Server 2008. SQL server performance is not consistent through out the day. For example, a procedure that takes less than 5 seconds usually, takes around 30 to 45 seconds sometimes. In a few cases, this procedures has taken even 180 seconds. When we did a little bit of troubleshooting, we felt, though not sure, that the was hardly any load on the server.

So to understand what is/are causing the server become slow, we thought of monitoring disk space, memory, cup load etc for 24/7. We found powershell scripts at [this link](http://refactoringself.com/powershell-system-monitor/) and used them. But they are not polished and do not seem work well. Any ideas, pointers to help us monitor this server for its heath is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly would you like to see in the script? I actually wrote the script you are talking about. I would love to get more detail.

Comment: @john, I would like to get all important performance metrics that would let me know whether server is performing optimally or not

Answer (score 0):

Probably a Bit Late but you should have a look at [PAL](http://pal.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with Windows Performance Monitor. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2424491

There is also a wide array of other tools for monitoring windows server performance. I have compiled an extensive list: https://checkpanel.com/resources/windows-server-performance-monitoring-tools